# Error setting multiple auth - undefined constant

Tags: laravel

```
My code is:

public function up() 

{ 
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) 
    { 

        $table->increments('id'); 
        $table->string('name'); 
        $table->string('email', 150)->unique(); 
        $table->string('username', 150)->unique(); 
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable(); 
        $table->boolean(‘isAdmin’)->nullable(); 
        $table->string('password', 150); $table->rememberToken(); 
        $table->timestamps(); }); 
}
```

[Error in cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcBIh.png)
[Code / Migrations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORq8D.png)

Can someone help me?
I already tried to switch the nullable on admin to default(false) but that didn't work

Comment: Please put some code or your error here, We can't help you with this image.

Comment: change your '' surrounding is_admin, you are now using the wrong backticks

Comment: public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email', 150)->unique();
            $table->string('username', 150)->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->boolean(‘isAdmin’)->nullable();
            $table->string('password', 150);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

Comment: @JasperHelmich can you be more specific, I'm new into laravel

Comment: Your syntax is wrong....

Comment: your highlighting even points it out.....

Comment: @PedroPires Please check this answer you will get an idea of it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please update your migration file like:

```
    public function up() { 
      Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) { 
         $table->increments('id'); 
         $table->string('name'); 
         $table->string('email', 150)->unique(); 
         $table->string('username', 150)->unique();       
         $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable(); 
         $table->boolean('isAdmin')->nullable(); 
         $table->string('password', 150); 
         $table->rememberToken(); 
         $table->timestamps(); 
       }); 
   }
```

**Updated Answer**

```
public function up() { 
      Schema::create('users', function ($table) { 
         $table->increments('id'); 
         $table->string('name'); 
         $table->string('email', 150)->unique(); 
         $table->string('username', 150)->unique();       
         $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable(); 
         $table->boolean('isAdmin')->default(false);
         $table->string('password', 150); 
         $table->rememberToken(); 
         $table->timestamps(); 
       }); 
   }
```

Your function like:

```
public function index() { 
 return view('home'); 
}

public function admin() { 
 return view('admin'); 
}
```

**Note**: Mainly update `isAdmin` field in migration file

Comment: Now when I'm executing the php artisan serve command, it shows this on my localhost:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\teste1901\app\Http\Kernel.php on line 62

Comment: I'm getting the error " syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC) " when I try to switch to my login/register page.

The code of my function is:

    public function index()
    {
        public function index()
        {
            return view('home');
        }
            public function admin()
        {
            return view('admin');
        }
    }

Comment: @PedroPires: Please check my answer and may be you have to not proper close your braces so

Answer (score 0):

First of all put your code here not image. Change the line to

```
$table->boolean('isAdmin')->nullable()
```

you must use quotation.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong quotation inside your code, Use single quotes `'` instead of ` on isAdmin

```
public function up() 
{ 
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) 
    { 

        $table->increments('id'); 
        $table->string('name'); 
        $table->string('email', 150)->unique(); 
        $table->string('username', 150)->unique(); 
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable(); 
        $table->boolean(‘isAdmin’)->nullable(); 
        $table->string('password', 150); $table->rememberToken(); 
        $table->timestamps(); }); 
}
```

**Change this line**

```
$table->boolean(‘isAdmin’)->nullable();
```

**to**

```
$table->boolean('isAdmin')->nullable();
```